How to dynamically convert a string into (and revert from) UTF8 special font characters?
How to dynamically convert a string into (and revert from) UTF8 special font characters "on-the-fly" using PHP functions?
For example,
echo cvtIntoSpclUTF8FntChars('script', 'Hello, World!');

becomes…
ℋℯℴ, ℴ!

and...
echo rvtFromSpclUTF8FntChars('ℋℯℴ, ℴ!');

becomes...
Hello, World!


This is my solution.
<?php

/* 2 global arrays used to convert a string to and from special UTF8 font characters. [BEGIN] */

$utf8_norm_fnt_char_arr = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z', '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '!', '?', '.', ',', '"', "'"];

$utf8_spcl_fnt_type_arr = array 
    (
        'serifBold' => ['', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '❗', '❓', '.', ',', '"', "'"],
        'serifItalic' => ['', '', '', '', '', '', '', 'ℎ', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '!', '?', '.', ',', '"', "'"],
        'serifBoldItalic' => ['', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '❗', '❓', '.', ',', '"', "'"],
        'sans' => ['', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '!', '?', '.', ',', '"', "'"],
        'sansBold' => ['', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '❗', '❓', '.', ',', '"', "'"],
        'sansItalic' => ['', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '!', '?', '.', ',', '"', "'"],
        'sansBoldItalic' => ['', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '❗', '❓', '.', ',', '"', "'"],
        'script' => ['', '', '', '', 'ℯ', '', 'ℊ', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', 'ℴ', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', 'ℬ', '', '', 'ℰ', 'ℱ', '', 'ℋ', 'ℐ', '', '', 'ℒ', 'ℳ', '', '', '', '', 'ℛ', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '!', '?', '.', ',', '"', "'"],
        'scriptBold' => ['', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '❗', '❓', '.', ',', '"', "'"],
        'fraktur' => ['', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', 'ℭ', '', '', '', '', 'ℌ', 'ℑ', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', 'ℜ', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', 'ℨ', '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '!', '?', '.', ',', '"', "'"],
        'frakturBold' => ['', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '❗', '❓', '.', ',', '"', "'"],
        'monospace' => ['', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '！', '？', '．', '，', '"', '＇'],
        'fullwidth' => ['ａ', 'ｂ', 'ｃ', 'ｄ', 'ｅ', 'ｆ', 'ｇ', 'ｈ', 'ｉ', 'ｊ', 'ｋ', 'ｌ', 'ｍ', 'ｎ', 'ｏ', 'ｐ', 'ｑ', 'ｒ', 'ｓ', 'ｔ', 'ｕ', 'ｖ', 'ｗ', 'ｘ', 'ｙ', 'ｚ', 'Ａ', 'Ｂ', 'Ｃ', 'Ｄ', 'Ｅ', 'Ｆ', 'Ｇ', 'Ｈ', 'Ｉ', 'Ｊ', 'Ｋ', 'Ｌ', 'Ｍ', 'Ｎ', 'Ｏ', 'Ｐ', 'Ｑ', 'Ｒ', 'Ｓ', 'Ｔ', 'Ｕ', 'Ｖ', 'Ｗ', 'Ｘ', 'Ｙ', 'Ｚ', '０', '１', '２', '３', '４', '５', '６', '７', '８', '９', '！', '？', '．', '，', '"', '＇'],
        'doublestruck' => ['', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', 'ℂ', '', '', '', '', 'ℍ', '', '', '', '', '', 'ℕ', '', 'ℙ', 'ℚ', 'ℝ', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', 'ℤ', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '❕', '❔', '.', ',', '"', "'"],
        'capitalized' => ['ᴀ', 'ʙ', 'ᴄ', 'ᴅ', 'ᴇ', 'ꜰ', 'ɢ', 'ʜ', 'ɪ', 'ᴊ', 'ᴋ', 'ʟ', 'ᴍ', 'ɴ', 'ᴏ', 'ᴘ', 'q', 'ʀ', 'ꜱ', 'ᴛ', 'ᴜ', 'ᴠ', 'ᴡ', 'x', 'ʏ', 'ᴢ', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z', '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '﹗', '﹖', '﹒', '﹐', '"', "'"],
        'circled' => ['ⓐ', 'ⓑ', 'ⓒ', 'ⓓ', 'ⓔ', 'ⓕ', 'ⓖ', 'ⓗ', 'ⓘ', 'ⓙ', 'ⓚ', 'ⓛ', 'ⓜ', 'ⓝ', 'ⓞ', 'ⓟ', 'ⓠ', 'ⓡ', 'ⓢ', 'ⓣ', 'ⓤ', 'ⓥ', 'ⓦ', 'ⓧ', 'ⓨ', 'ⓩ', 'Ⓐ', 'Ⓑ', 'Ⓒ', 'Ⓓ', 'Ⓔ', 'Ⓕ', 'Ⓖ', 'Ⓗ', 'Ⓘ', 'Ⓙ', 'Ⓚ', 'Ⓛ', 'Ⓜ', 'Ⓝ', 'Ⓞ', 'Ⓟ', 'Ⓠ', 'Ⓡ', 'Ⓢ', 'Ⓣ', 'Ⓤ', 'Ⓥ', 'Ⓦ', 'Ⓧ', 'Ⓨ', 'Ⓩ', '⓪', '①', '②', '③', '④', '⑤', '⑥', '⑦', '⑧', '⑨', '!', '?', '.', ',', '"', "'"],
        'parenthesized' => ['⒜', '⒝', '⒞', '⒟', '⒠', '⒡', '⒢', '⒣', '⒤', '⒥', '⒦', '⒧', '⒨', '⒩', '⒪', '⒫', '⒬', '⒭', '⒮', '⒯', '⒰', '⒱', '⒲', '⒳', '⒴', '⒵', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '⓿', '⑴', '⑵', '⑶', '⑷', '⑸', '⑹', '⑺', '⑻', '⑼', '!', '?', '.', ',', '"', "'"],
        'underlinedSingle' => ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z', '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '!', '?', '.', ',', '"', "'"],
        'underlinedDouble' => ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z', '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '!', '?', '.', ',', '"', "'"],
        'strikethroughSingle' => ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z', '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '!', '?', '.', ',', '"', "'"],
        'crosshatch' => ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z', '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '!', '?', '.', ',', '"', "'"]
    );

/* 2 global arrays used to convert a string to and from special UTF8 font characters. [END] */

/* A global function to convert a string into special UTF8 font characters. [BEGIN] */

/* Valid Font Types ($utf8_spcl_fnt_type): 

'serifBold', 'serifItalic', 'serifBoldItalic', 'sans', 'sansBold', 'sansItalic', 'script', 'scriptBold', 
'fraktur', 'frakturBold', 'monospace', 'fullwidth', 'doublestruck', 'capitalized', 'circled', 'parenthesized', 
'underlinedSingle', 'underlinedDouble', 'strikethroughSingle', 'crosshatch' 
*/

if (!function_exists('cvtIntoSpclUTF8FntChars'))
    {
        function cvtIntoSpclUTF8FntChars($utf8_spcl_fnt_type, $str)
            {
                global $utf8_norm_fnt_char_arr, $utf8_spcl_fnt_type_arr;

                if (isset($utf8_spcl_fnt_type) && is_array($utf8_spcl_fnt_type_arr) && array_key_exists($utf8_spcl_fnt_type, $utf8_spcl_fnt_type_arr))
                    {
                        $str = str_replace($utf8_norm_fnt_char_arr, $utf8_spcl_fnt_type_arr[$utf8_spcl_fnt_type], $str);
                    };

                return $str;
            };
    };

/* A global function to convert a string into special UTF8 font characters. [END] */

/* A global function to revert a string from special UTF8 font characters. [BEGIN] */

if (!function_exists('rvtFromSpclUTF8FntChars'))
    {
        function rvtFromSpclUTF8FntChars($str)
            {
                global $utf8_norm_fnt_char_arr, $utf8_spcl_fnt_type_arr;

                foreach ($utf8_spcl_fnt_type_arr as $utf8_spcl_fnt_char_arr)
                    {
                        $str = str_replace($utf8_spcl_fnt_char_arr, $utf8_norm_fnt_char_arr, $str);
                    };

                return $str;
            };
    };

/* A global function to revert a string from special UTF8 font characters. [END] */

?>

Usage:
echo cvtIntoSpclUTF8FntChars('script', 'Hello, World!');

becomes…
ℋℯℴ, ℴ!

and...
echo rvtFromSpclUTF8FntChars('ℋℯℴ, ℴ!');

becomes...
Hello, World!

